# Find the number of $X$ from start to end

Tags: arithmetic

If I wanted to figure out for example, how many tutorial exercises I completed today.

And the first question I do is **question $45$**,

And the last question I do is **question $55$**

If I do $55-45$ I get $10$.

But I have actually done $11$ questions:
$1=45$, $2=46$, $3=47$, $4=48$, $5=49$, $6=50$, $7=51$, $8=52$, $9=53$, $10=54$, $11=55$.

Is there any way to know when I can just subtract. Or is the rule I always have to add $1$ when I subtract?

Comment: You have to count the number of exercises done today : i.e. those starting from the number 45 up to the number 55 (extremes included). Thus, the exercises you have **not** done today are those up to 44; conclusion: subtract from the last exercise done today the number of exercises not done, i.e. 44.

Comment: Just so you know, [you are not alone.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) This is one of the [two hard problems in computer science](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html). ;)

Answer (score 34):

If you want to use pure subtraction, here's how you'd do it:

At the beginning, you were at the start of problem **45**.

At the end, you were at the end of problem 55, *which is the start of problem **56***.

And $56-45=11$. You finished $11$ problems.

---

The reason for the offset is because you're measuring from different places from each problem - the *start* of 45, but the *end* of 46.

Comment: +1 for giving a rationalization of _why_ the fencepost error occurs.

Comment: @wchargin +1 to your comment for containing the phrase "fencepost error", because it's good for people to know the name of this very common error.

Answer (score 14):

Suggestion: if you'd done questions $1$ to $N$, you'd have done $N$ questions. So if you start at question $44$ and finish at question $55$, subtract $43$ from both $44$ and $55$ to reduce to the easy case where the question numbers begin with $1$.

Comment: This a good idea. In my maths exam I often double-guess myself whether I should add one or not (and waste exam time), so I will just follow this method every time.

Answer (score 10):

You'll always need to add one in such cases. Consider - if you do problems 45 through 45, you'll have done 45-45 + 1 = 1 questions.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether the range includes or not its endpoints. For example, let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then:

- $45 \lt n \lt 55\quad$ has $\;55-45-1=9$ solutions;
- $45 \le n \lt 55\;$ and $\;45 \lt n \le 55\quad$ both have has $\;55-45=10$ solutions;
- $45 \le n \le 55\quad$ has $\;55-45+1=11$ solutions.

---

[ EDIT ] In the original post, `the first question I do is question 45` and `the last question I do is question 55` imply that the range is inclusive of both endpoints $45,55$ which falls in the latter case among the above, so the correct answer is $55-45+1=11$.

Comment: The question makes it quite clear that the range includes the endpoints.

Comment: I do still find the answer useful as it shows me in which cases I can't subtract (although I kind of knew this, I couldn't specifically write it down or explain it).

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks, edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: Please don't use codeblocks for something which is not actual code. Quotemarks and emphasis or a quoteblock would work far better.

Comment: @Nij I don't think anyone could possibly mistake that for actual code, so there is no confusion about it. The reason code blocks *are* sometimes used for quotes is that there are no [Inline Quotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120361/addition-of-inline-quotes), and the highlight is visually easier to follow than the alternatives.

Comment: @dxiv That's not the point. Screenreaders can't tell the difference, so you're giving the middle finger to low-sighted people every time you do it. And if you've ever tried to use the site on mobile, you know more than a few words in a codeblock is a scrolling UX nightmare. So, please **be nice** to everybody who uses SE, not just the people who are well-sighted and have more than 720p.

Answer (score 2):

If you started at the question 15 and finished at the question 15; how many question have you answered?

Imagine a list of exercises to be done in order. Some of them are marked as done already. You start from the first unmarked question.

> Every time you complete an excercise you mark it, thus increasing the number of the first excercise waiting to be done.

This way the *number of excercises done* in some time is an *incremet of a number of the first excercise not done yet*.
Since you started with question 45 (so 45 was the first question NOT done then) and you stopped after question 55 (so the first question NOT done yet is $56 = 55+1$ now), you have answered $(55+1)-45=11$ questions.

Put it another way:

when you started your work, the last question answered was number $44 = 45-1$, and now it is $55$; the number of questions you answered today is an increment of the number of questions answered: $55 - (45-1) = 11$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to calculate is the sum of exercises you did from question $a$ to question $b$.
You have $1$ exercise per question so the number of exercises is :
$$\underbrace{\sum_{a}^b 1}_{\text{Sum from a to b}} =\underbrace{\sum_{1}^b 1}_{\text{Sum from 1 to b}} - \underbrace{\sum_{1}^{a-1} 1}_{\text{Sum from 1 to a-1}} = b-(a-1) = b-a+1 $$
Therefore, if you did question 45 to 55 you have $a=45$, $b=55$, so you did $55-45+1=11$ exercises